# Как открыть окно чужого сайта и выполнить 2 функции ? Автоматизация

Tags: javascript, steam-web-api

Здравствуйте. Я немного начал заниматься торговлей в STEAM, а именно обменом вещей. Но очень уж много летит предложений, так что решил сделать бот, который будет парсить цены ну и если мне предлагают больше - менять. Все дотошно просто. Но мне нужна небольшая помощь в программной части, а то я не очень понимаю как вызывать функции на стороннем сайте.

1. Пишу расширение для Google Chrome.
2. Что бы принять обмен, нужно открыть страницу с обменом.

Вот ф-я открытия окна:

```
<a href="javascript:ShowTradeOffer( '564091454' );" class="whiteLink">Ответить на предложение</a>
```

После, открывается страница:

[image: Страница обмена]

Я так понял, что id операции хранится только в url:
https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/564091454/

Где нужно поставить checkbox и после нажать на кнопку. Вот, собственно, код:

```
<div class="readystate short" id="you_notready" onclick="ToggleReady( true );">   -   это chexbox;
```

После нажатия на который появляется кнопка.

```
<div id="trade_confirmbtn" class="trade_confirmbtn ellipsis active" onclick="ConfirmTradeOffer();">
```

Теперь о том. что я уже сделал. Собственно, ничего особенного, просто через `XMLHttpRequest` нахожу по очереди обмен и вытаскиваю с него id.

Если кому нужно - код:

```
AvtoBumpBot2();
setInterval(AvtoBumpBot2, 10000);

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    AvtoBumpBot2();
});

function AvtoBumpBot2() {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198164551531/tradeoffers", true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
        {
            if (xhr.responseText) 
            {
                chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "../images/icon.png" });
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: "" });
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: "#ff0000" });

                var data = xhr.responseText;
                var gl = $('.profile_leftcol', data);
                var count = gl.children('.tradeoffer').size();
                var feed_id = 0;

                if (count > 0) {

                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: count.toString() });

                feed_id = gl.children('.tradeoffer:first').attr('id'); 
                feed_id = parseInt(feed_id.replace(/\D+/g,""));

                // Bot

                     //Тут собственно и должна открываться страница с id: feed_id;

                // End Bot.

                }

                    var content = 'Count trade ofeers: ' + count.toString() + '<br> ID: ' + feed_id.toString();
                    $('#wrapper').html(content);

            } else {
                chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "../images/lock-icon.png" });
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: "?" });
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: "#ccc" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Очень жду помощи. Очень хочу сделать, что задумал, но пока опыта не хватает... В колледже закончил второй курс, нас только паскалю учили, так что пробую сам, но очень сложно уж дается...

Comment: Их функции вы не вызовите. Вам нужно вызывать события, они и вызовут функции, но мне кажется Вальве не пеньки и защита есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызов клика по ID элемента:

```
document.getElementById('you_notready').click();
document.getElementById('trade_confirmbtn').click();
```

Готов ли человек с той стороны интернетов придётся в цикле проверять, и лишь потом выполнять второй клик. Это тоже несложная операция. Надо лишь проверять появился ли какой-то класс у определённого элемента. У какого-то он точно появиться должен, чтобы показать готовность.

Comment: Да, спасибо, но меня интересовал немного другой вопрос, а именно: как открыть нужную страницу и на ней сделать нужные манипуляции ? Или скажите как это называется, просто у нас с гуглом по данному запросу большие разногласия...